# undefined method `downcase' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2

```
describe GameSystem::Client do

  def client
    GameSystem::Client.new(signature_method: 'HMAC-SHA1', oauth_key: 'kk', oauth_secret: 'bb', oauth_access_token_url: 'https:://localhost')
  end

  before :each do
    WebMock.reset!       
  end

  describe 'response' do

    context 'wrong path' do
      it 'raises JSON::ParserError on invalid return value' do
        stub_request(:get,"https://games.com/game_id/invalid_id").to_return(:status => 200, :body => 'invalid json', :headers => {})
        Rails.logger.info "#{client.games_by_id("invalid_id")}"
      end
    end
  end

end
```

Can anyone let me know what i have been doing wrong or what i could do different ?.

It basically throws this error at the line

`@access_token = @consumer.get_access_token(nil)` in my client

Answer (score 0):

It'd be good if you could be a bit more specific on what you're trying to do.

The error is pretty self explanatory. You're getting `downcase for nil:NilClass` because you're trying to call `downcase` for a nil object...Provide more information and we'll be able to help better.

Comment: Maybe this answer should be a comment. However, the point still stands, his code somewhere must be calling `downcase` on a nil object...He never provided the code of the method `get_access_token` Which is probably where the downcase is...

Answer (score 0):

I realize this question was from way back, but I just ran into this issue in a test suite.  Sounded familiar.

My error was

```
Failure/Error: get :index
  ActionView::Template::Error:
    undefined method `downcase' for nil:NilClass
```

As it turns out, i'm using `mobile-fu` and I was stubbing `is_mobile_device?` without stubbing also `mobile_device`.  Somewhere along the way, `mobile-fu` was trying to downcase the device name, which was `nil`.  By adding a stub for the `mobile_device`, things cleared up. In a before block in the specs, I added:

```
controller.stub(:is_mobile_device? => true, :mobile_device => 'iphone')
```

If you're not using mobile-fu, you probably have a different issue.  I was able to track the actual issue down with `pry` and `pry-debugger`.  Definitely worthwhile tools to look into.